# After loading iframe Cordova fails on plugins

Tags: cordova

I have a Cordova (6.5.0) application which runs fine until I access another page using an iframe. The other page has been downloaded and saved to a folder in cordova.file.externalDataDirectory
The downloaded page also uses cordova.js the page looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="file:///android_asset/www/" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
Test page
<script>
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    console.log("ready");
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After loading the page in an iframe 2 messages will appear in the debugger

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
```

From that point on the host application cannot call any plugins.
However, if I remove the cordova.js link from the iframe page then the host application is not affected. I need the iframe page to have access to the cordova features how do I do it without creating problems for the host?

EDIT:
By changing from an iframe to the inAppBrowser the problem is isolated to the child page. That is, there are no more errors in the host but the child page still shows the errors as before.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this problem, for now the only way I have found around this problem is to not load cordova.js but rather access all the plugins via window.parent[plugin_name]

Not really an answer as I would prefer to know why the expected behaviour doesn't work.